# Can someone please explain the output of the following code

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

     int arr[100];
     char *q ;
     int *p;
     arr[0]= "0xabcd";
     p = arr;
     q = p;
     printf("%x  %x",*p,*q);
     return 0;
}
```

Output - `4005e4  ffffffe4`

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: A whole load of UB....

Comment: What, exactly, did you expect?

Comment: You found this in some book?

Comment: No , It  is one of interview question.

Answer (score 3):

This code is full of **undefined behavior**, two instances are caught by `gcc`'s warnings (so, always enable compiler warnings!):

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -oub ub.c
ub.c: In function 'main':
ub.c:9:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      arr[0]= "0xabcd";
            ^
ub.c:11:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      q = p;
        ^
```

The third is here:

```
 printf("%x  %x",*p,*q);
```

`%x` expects an `unsigned int` but you're passing an `int` and a `char`.

You better shouldn't reason about the output of an undefined program.

---

What your program does is to put the (undefined!) result of a conversion from `char *` (a pointer to your string literal) to `int` in the first element of an array. It takes two pointers to this first element, one of those of an incompatible type (`char *`). then, it tries to print *what is left from the pointer in `arr[0]`* through both these pointers as an unsigned int in hex format. The second one just reads a single byte, that's probably a negative value, but as `printf()` expects an `int`, the negative value is expanded to 4 bytes. You really should forget about all this undefined nonsense and write correct programs, because all I outlined here just **happens by accident** because of the way your concrete implementation works on your machine. It could just as well paint your cat green instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Felix, I also compiled the code and got the same warnings.. 
FYI this nonsense question is not written by me, it was asked in one of the interview.